# Alt+Q doesn’t work in edit mode anymore

Tags: 3d-view

I'm working with a MacBook, so I use Alt+Q to simulate the Numpad shortcuts.
It works fine in object mode, but when I switch to edit mode.... nothing happens.
Is there a preset I need to activate?
I'm using Blender 3.0 Beta (yes... I know, Beta, but I'm sure it worked in Alpha status all the time too!?).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this menu?
[image]

If yes, this pie menu and Alt+Q shortcut is part of **3D Viewport Pie Menus** addon

Are you sure that you enabled this addon when you updated to new version? Because it works in 3.0.0

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the pie menu I'm talking about.
I activated it in the preferences and it also works in object mode, but not in edit mode.
That is exactly my problem.

Comment: maybe you have somehow changed the keymap for it? Not really sure why it doesn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

I faced this add-on's issue the first time I tried Blender 3.0 on January 2022, but I think people already reported it on developer.blender.org so maybe we can just wait the next update. For now I'am still using 2.9+ just so I can use this add-on.

For the time being, you can read this https://developer.blender.org/T94325
there was a keymap changing and we have to change the keymap to use this <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Q</kbd> add on